# Maximun norm over the complex sequence

Tags: banach-spaces, normed-spaces

Is  $C_0$ (the space of all the complex sequences that satisfy $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty }{x_n} =0$ ) is  a Banach space relative to the maximum norm ( $\|x\| =max|x_n| $) and pairwise operations ?

Is it enough for the proof to show that the norm satisfy with the next norm properties:

For all $x_1, x_2 ... \in X$ :

- $ 0 \le \left \| x \right \|$
- $ x = \vec{0} \Leftrightarrow \left \| x \right \| = 0 $
- $ \left \| \ \alpha\cdot \ x \right \| = \ |\alpha| \cdot \left \| x \right \|$
- $\left \| x + y \right \| \le \left \| x \right \| + \left \| y \right \| $

TIA

Comment: You also need to show that $C_0$ is *complete* when equipped with your norm.

Comment: @mrf How do I show it ?

Answer (score 2):

We know that the set of bounded sequences $\ell^{\infty}(\mathbb{C})$ is a Banach space, so if we prove that $c_0$ is a closed subset of $\ell^{\infty}(\mathbb{C})$ we're done.

Let $(x^p)_p$ a sequence of $c_0$ that converges to $x$, we must prove that $x\in c_0$.

We have: for $\epsilon>0$ there's $P\in\mathbb{N}$, s.t $\forall p\geq P$ $||x^p-x||=\sup_n|x^p_n-x_n|<\epsilon$.

We fix $p=P$, then the sequence $(x^P_n)_n$ converges to $0$, there's $N\in\mathbb{N}$ s.t $\forall n\geq N$ we have $|x^P_n|<\epsilon$.

Now, $\forall n\geq N$, $|x_n|\leq |x_n-x^P_n|+|x_n^P|\leq 2\epsilon. $ Hence the sequence $x\in c_0$.